# Bootstrap validation verification

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a HTML form and I've applied Bootstrap validation (via [Bootstrap Validator](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/) plugin) on it. It works on "save" button, but I've got an `onclick` attribute set on the same button. I want it to be executed if form validation is true.

Here is my example: I want the `SpecialtySave_OnClick()` function to be executed only if the form is valid.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" onclick="specialtyDetail.SpecialtySave_OnClick();">Save</button>
```

Comment: Which plugin are you using for "Bootstrap form validation"? (as Bootstrap doesn't support natively this feature)

Comment: I used bootstrap 3.0

Comment: Bootstrap 3 doesn't validate forms. Please be more specific.

Comment: I used bootstrap 3.0 validation $('#frmSpecialtyDetail') .bootstrapValidator({ message: 'This value is not valid', feedbackIcons: { valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok', invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove', validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh' }, fields: { Short group: '.col-md-6', validators: { notEmpty: { message: 'Short Name is –

Comment: Sooooooo... You doesn't use "Bootstrap 3 validation" (which doesn't exist), **but** "Bootstrap Validator", which is an external plugin as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what kind of validation are you using but common thing to check form is something like this

```
 $("form").submit(function() {
            var result = $("form").valid();
            if (result == false) {
                SpecialtySave_OnClick()
            }
            else {
                 ....
            }
]);
```

Comment: I used bootstrap 3.0 validation  $('#frmSpecialtyDetail')
            .bootstrapValidator({
                message: 'This value is not valid',
                feedbackIcons: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {
                    Short
                        group: '.col-md-6',
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Short Name is

Answer (score 0):

I would use some kind of jQuery for this.

```
$('#submit-btn').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($('#number').val() == "10"){
    $('#form').submit();
  } else {
    alert('Type 10!');
  }
});
```

Here you can see a example: http://www.bootply.com/6htwDQySDc

Answer (score 0):

Try this code `onclick="if(return $(form).data('bootstrapValidator').isValid()){SpecialtySave_OnClick();}"`. I Make this with my logic and hope this help you.